# Unexpected getter behaviour

Tags: java

I'm having a little problem with the challenge assignment for one of my courses. This code is supposed to list all of the contacts contained in the array list by names of the contacts. I have made a subclass Contact which contains the number of the contact and the number.

The problem I'm having is with outputting the names of the contacts. Instead of the expected "Number of the contact" followed by the name, I only get the number. The other getter of that class works, if I change the `.getName()` to `.getNumber()` in the for loop, it will have the expected output of a "number of the contact" followed by the actual number stored in the contact.

```
 private void storeContact() {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    System.out.println("Please enter a contact name.");
    contact.setName(scanner.nextLine());
    scanner.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the phone number for the contact");
    contact.setNumber(scanner.nextLong());
    contacts.add(contact);
}
private void listAllContact(){
   if(contacts.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + contacts.get(i).getName());
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Contact book is empty.");
    }
}
```

Contact class:

```
class Contact{
    private long number;
    private String name;

    public long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you set the name anywhere?

Comment: By "Number of the contact" I meant (i+1) which shows the position in the contact book, should have made that clearer.

Comment: Yes, I have a separate method which saves new contacts and requires them to have a name and a number.

Comment: @Bax he did .getName(), which is a string

Comment: `(i+1) + ") " + contacts.get(i). getNumber()` lists the numbers

Comment: @danielp are you adding contacts to the list before the name has been set?

Comment: Don't you think it would be really useful to add constructor in `Contact` class, taking `String` and `long` as arguments? You could easily set `name` and `number` of contact that way. Try to include this in your `Contact` class: `public Contact(String name, long number) {this.name = name; this.number = number;}` That way you can create new Contact like this: `Contact john = new Contact("John", 123456L);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you did not provide a full example I tried to infer it

```
static List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setNumber(-17);
    contact.setName("contact name");
    contacts.add(contact);
    listAllContact();
}

private static void listAllContact() {
    if (contacts.size() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println((i + 1) + contacts.get(i).getName());
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Contact book is empty.");
    }
}

static class Contact {
    private long number;
    private String name;

    public long getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(long number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

The output is as expected

> 1contact name

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided seems OK.

The problem should be when you set names and phone numbers.

If you provide them, we can search for a problem.